# Use of undeclared type 'UITableViewSection' even though UIKit is imported

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I'm trying to create a reference to my TableView's static section. I control-drag the section from the Document Outline ("My Section", highlighted in the second screenshot) into the associated code file and Xcode offers to connect to a new UITableViewSection outlet (the "Type" field was pre-filled with "UITableViewSection"):

[image: Creating outlet]

But then Xcode immediately complains telling me it doesn't know what UITableViewSection is:

[image]

I've imported UIKit, so that's not it. I can't find any documentation for UITableViewSection. It seems to not exist, but then why would Xcode let me drag it into the file to create an outlet?

Comment: Where did you find a class called `UITableViewSection` to drag?  Is it just a name you created?

Comment: You should use table view delegate methods to work with sections

Comment: I didn't make up the name UITableViewSection. It showed up (see the dropdown in the first screenshot, which was pre-filled) when I control-dragged "My Section" from the Document Outline (see the highlighted row in the left pane of my second screenshot). I was just curious why Xcode would try to create an outlet with a type that doesn't exist.

Comment: This is a defect in Xcode that should be fixed.

Answer (score 5):

You can not declare UITableViewSection like that, as there as no class available with that name.
You can do it simply by creating a custom prototype UITableViewCell and can use it custom section header like below-

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SectionHeader") as! CustomHeaderUITableViewCell
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}
```

Comment: you should not dequeue a cell to act as an header

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same thing and same error occured. What i did was instead of creating an outlet on the section, i created an outlet on the Content View

```
@IBOutlet var editCountdownTableViewCell: UITableViewCell!
```

I am creating it because i want to be able to hide and show.